# Emacs open run command save exit

Tags: shell, emacs

I use [google-c-style.el](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-c-style.el) for C/C++ projects in Emacs. Like many Emacs modes, the indentation is automatically set. For any given file I can open it, select the whole document, then press Tab to reset all indentations, save it, then exit.

I have a large code base that I'd like to perform this procedure on, but I want to do it automatically from the command line or a shell script. What is the best way to accomplish this? Assume I have already found the list of files I want to run it on.

Comment: Have you tried anything using emacs with the `batch` and `eval` arguments?  If so, what have you tried?  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BatchMode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs [batch mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BatchMode) is the right answer for this problem (thanks @lawlist). The link even has an "indenting C files" example.

```
emacs --batch sample.cpp \
    --eval '(indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)' \
    -f save-buffer
```

According to the Emacs [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html), the --batch switch implies --no-init-file which keeps Emacs from loading your custom configurations. As a result, my indentation was only that of the default C++ mode, not the google-c-style as I intended. The solution is to tell Emacs to load your settings file before opening the file.

```
emacs --load ~/.emacs.d/init.el \
    --batch sample.cpp \
    --eval '(indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)' \
    -f save-buffer
```

You can also create an Emacs script and run it on a set of files like shown [here](http://www.cslab.pepperdine.edu/warford/BatchIndentationEmacs.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any package that does this automatically. However, I have used the pattern below to accomplish this for specific tasks. You must implement the actual function that does the work, in this example `(my-do-something)`.

```
(defun my-do-something-file (f)
  (let ((buf (get-file-buffer f))
        (kill-it nil))
    (unless buf
      (setq buf (find-file-noselect f))
      (setq kill-it t))
    (save-excursion
      (set-buffer buf)
      (unless buffer-read-only
        (my-do-something)    ;; Implement this.
        (let ((require-final-newline nil))
          (save-buffer))))
    (when kill-it
      (kill-buffer buf))))


(defun my-do-something-directory (dir)
  (interactive "DDirectory: ")
  (dolist (f (directory-files dir t))
    (if (not (member (file-name-nondirectory f) '("." ".." ".svn")))
        (if (file-directory-p f)
            (my-do-something-directory f)
          (my-do-something-file f)))))
```

Comment: This shows the process within Emacs, but not how to automate the process. Also, the indent-region function appears to do everything I need.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that you want to do it in batch mode. This code is intended to be applied to a directory tree, but interactively from within Emacs. However, it runs the "core" function on all files in the directory tree,  so maybe you won't need a batch command.